# What guarantees are there on inter-thread visibility of filesystem changes on Linux/OS X?

Tags: linux, multithreading, macos, filesystems

**Background:** I have an application that contains several threads (typically 2-4). At certain points in the running of that application, the threads need to simultaneously open separate log files. The files sit in a common directory. When opening the files, I just need to ensure that they have distinct names, named with a one-up counter. This application runs primarily on Linux and OS X.

> **Example:** If I have 4 threads start logging at once, I would expect to see the following files appear:
>
> - `log_file-<date>-<time>-1.log`
> - `log_file-<date>-<time>-2.log`
> - `log_file-<date>-<time>-3.log`
> - `log_file-<date>-<time>-4.log`

Right now, I'm doing the above using a routine like the below (pseudocode), which is executed in each thread:

```
lock mutex;
int i = 1;
while (true)
{
    filename = "log_file-<date>-<time>_" + to_string(i) + ".log";
    if (filename does not exist)
    {
        create file called filename;
        break;
    }
    i += 1;        
}
unlock mutex;
```

This works, *most of the time*. However, I'm seeing the occasional case where I have more than one thread choose the same file name. After introducing some logging statements to this process, I see a case that boils down to the following:

- Thread #1 chooses a filename, say, `log-file-1.log`.
- Thread #1 touches the file (by opening it for creation and immediately closing it).
- Thread #1 verifies that the file exists on disk (via `stat()` or similar system call).
- Thread #1 releases the mutex.
- Thread #2 acquires the mutex.
- Thread #2 checks to see if `log-file-1.log` exists (via `stat()` or similar system call).
- Much to my surprise, thread #2 does **not** see the presence of the file created by thread #1, causing it to select the same filename (which breaks some stuff down the line in my application).

**Question:** Are there any guarantees as to the visibility of filesystem operations across threads? Are there filesystem analogs to the memory barriers that are needed in order to ensure proper visibility of memory accesses across threads?

Comment: Can you see if mounting the file system with the dirsync option fixes the problem?

Comment: @itisravi: That's not an option for my application, unfortunately, as I can't assume to have root access on the target machine.

Comment: Okay. Synchronization primitives are used to protect 'data' rather than 'logic', so maybe you can have a get_next_value_of_i() function that increments i under a mutex. Your threads can just call that function and create the file without needing to stat and check if it already exists.